# differences in quality of brush alphas

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I wanted to do a something like skin pores. I tried to do it with brush alphas but the quality of it was very low or was different in different areas. And here is my question: what affects the quality of the results when using alphas on brushes when texture painting? I will put some images to show what I mean. (I apologize for my English)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I make some alpha in gimp. I cant remebere where i found this one from the begining (this "skin").
Brush texture 1k:

[image]
[image]

Brush texture 4k:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe JPG is too lossy to be a good mask for a brush

Comment: Do you get the same result when painting in the UV/Image Editor? What is the target texture canvas resolution versus the actual brush image resolution?

Comment: When i used UV/Image Editor results was the same. Target texture is 1k. I was trying 1k and 4k brush texture resolution but nothing changed. I will update post with pictures of that. I am not sure if I answered your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I worked it out a quite some time ago, but maybe it will help someone else. I did bad UV mapping, begginer mistake.